# Help with has/are & have/is on a test question

Tags: quantifiers, quantificational-nouns

#### Most of the milk ____ <sub>A</sub> ____ gone bad.

#### Six gallons of milk ____ <sub>B</sub> ____ still in the refrigerator.

**Verb choices are has/are/have/is.**

Which verb should be used in both blanks?
Guide me please.

I am mostly interested in what tests and textbooks would want, not so much conversational English.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fewer_vs._less): "An extreme application of the prescriptivist rule can be seen in the examples "there is less flour in this canister" and "there are fewer cups (grains, pounds, bags, etc.) of flour in this canister", which are based on the reasoning that flour is uncountable whereas the unit used to measure the flour (cup etc.) is countable."

Comment: Please sir , try to make me understand.  I am not getting you.

Comment: My idea was that this question could be much clearer if the choices were given (two choices or four, as I mentioned in my first comment). The important thing, which I think your question is all about is whether "six gallons of milk" is countable. I believe that to most speakers, "six gallons of milk" is just "milk" (so it's uncountable), but to some books and tests, "six gallons of milk" is "six gallons" and that makes it countable, similar to the example given in Wikipedia: "there are fewer cups of flour in this canister".

Comment: Means here "are" is correct?

Comment: What @DamkerngT means is that it's a tricky question, and different people might give different answers. It would help a lot if you spent more time carefully explaining what you want. Do you want the answer that a textbook might give? Or do you want to know how most people would say it?

Comment: Sir,  explain it whatever tests and textbooks want.

Comment: user, it's best to add information like that into your question with an edit, not in an obscure comment down here. I've done it for you this time, but next time, you'll know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'll risk answering your question, and guessing what your textbook wants. Based on the first revision of your question, the answer would be:

> *Most of the milk **has** gone bad. Six gallons of milk **are** still in the refrigerator.*

---

In your first revision, your choices appeared to be two choices between:

> *Most of the milk ____ gone bad. Six gallons of milk ____ still in the refrigerator.*
>   a) *has -- are*
>   b) *have -- is*

The purpose of the test is about countability. I assume that you know that ***milk*** is uncountable. The test is a little more advanced than that: they want to test whether you know ***most of the milk*** or ***six gallons of milk*** is countable or not.

In standard English, ***most of the X*** doesn't change the countability of X, so *most of the milk* is still uncountable, because *milk* is uncountable. So the first part of the answer is ***has***.

The problem lies in ***six gallons of milk***. The textbook/classroom/proficiency-test English tends to be prescriptive, that is, it usually follows the rules that state how we should use the language, not how we really use it. In this kind of English, ***six gallons of milk*** is countable, because it's ***"six gallons"*** and we can count gallons. There are six gallons of it, so the latter part of the answer is ***are***.